# Replace .dll/.exe on a remote server by killing processes using these dll/exe

Tags: powershell, dll, process, remote-server, kill

New to Powershell. Trying to replace .dlls on a remote computer/server via powershell. I need to kill all the processes running on remote computer that are using the DLLs i need to replace at target folder on remote computer. There may be multiple folders with same name dlls and other processes on same machine using those non targeted dlls which are not to be touched. How can i obtain complete path of dlls and exe of processes running on remote computer. That will allow me to compare paths of targetted and actual server dlls to determine if i need to replace the dll/exe file or not.

$deployList arraylist has target paths and file names of all dlls and exe to be replaced. Eg: c:\xyz\dev\ver.dll
i tried using Get-Process but it was not returning process running on remote computer. Was working for processes on local machine only. Then used Get-WmiObject

`$processes = Get-WmiObject -Class -Class Win32_Process -ComputerName $TargetWinServer`

`foreach($deployFile in $deployList){
            foreach ($process in $processes) {
                  # $Executablepath = $process.ExecutablePath #This does not give path of all locked dll paths
                  $processid = $process.handle'
                  $ProcessName = $process.name`

**Need to obtain path of all .dll/.exe being used by this process that i want to extract in a variable $processes.path that i can iterate through?????**

```
   'foreach ($destdllPath in $processes.path) {
            if ( $destdllPath -eq $deployFile){
                write-host "Found: process file " $Executablepath " in " $ProcessName "ID:" Processid
                Taskkill /S $TargetServer  /PID $Processid
} #This will kill the process on remote server if the process is using the dll that needs to be repalced on target server
            }
        } `
```

pls ignore the closing braces

Comment: Killing processes can leave DLLs and files locked which defeats your goal.

Comment: then please suggest a work aorund to accomplish what i intend to do.... i need to replace a few upgraded dlls/.exe at target server out of all the dlls that exist in the application. This would ensure that only modules that are linked to concerned dlls are down during the deployment process. Is there a way to insert or replace dlls while they are being consumed.

Comment: I will be glad if someone can guide me on how the above can be achieved even if its not the most gracefull approach.

Comment: how to obtain modules that a process running on a remote computer has loaded using powershell